# conemu not responding when starting

Tags: windows, conemu

when i run conemu (at first it worked fine) ,i got this http://i58.tinypic.com/a0crw2.jpg
i tried uninstall and install it , i tried install the 32 bit version of it ,nothing worked still the same weird window.
i have windows 8.1 if it's help .
i mass a little bit with conemu settings ,but i dont think it should change somthing 'and even so ,it should not be deleted when i install+unistall it .
is it happened to anyone ,please help ...

.

Comment: As I've already said in the issue you are using old version.